# Why "if( variable = class)" return false?

Tags: php, class, variables, if-statement

I have this piece of code:

```
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags(md5($_POST['password']));
require_once '../classes/Login.php';
$Login = new Login;
if($message = $Login->checkUserLogin($username,$password))
 echo $message;
}
else{
 echo "Houston, we have problem";
}
```

And it write: "`Houston, we have problem`"

So I'm wondering why?

Sorry for my english. I hope you understand me!

Comment: Maybe either username or password or the `checkUserLogin()` method is wrong? Could you please print `$username` and `$password` before the test, to check which value they have and if they should be accepted by `checkUserLogin()`? And what is the code of `checkUserLogin()`?

Comment: Does it return an empty string or another falsy yet not false value?

Comment: Missing a brace `{` there are you?

Comment: Just as a matter of coding style, performing assignments in conditions is probably going to make debugging problems more difficult than they need to be.  Assign in one statement, check the condition in another statement.  There's no reason to combine them.  Indeed, it makes the code easier to read, especially considering the easily-glazed-over difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: What does $Login->checkUserLogin() return?

Comment: I added some source code - checkUserLogin function and username and password variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can assign a variable in an `IF` statement unless you'll simultaneously compare it to another variable or value. Here's another suggestion:

```
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags(md5($_POST['password']));
require_once '../classes/Login.php';
$Login = new Login;
$message = $Login->checkUserLogin($username,$password);
if($message != '') {
 echo $message;
}
else{
 echo "Houston, we have problem";
}
```

Sorry, there I go again with a suggestion. If you really just want to know why it doesn't work, I don't know how else to answer your question.

However, if you had something to compare `$message` to, you can use this!:

```
    if($messageToCompare == $message = $Login->checkUserLogin($username,$password)) {
```

It should help.

Comment: I think he tries to assign the value and wonders why he gets null.

Comment: @J.Lamer :: Sorry, one more thing.. This method.. you can only use it `once` in an `IF` statement. Otherwise, it won't work.. Just an fyi :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just simple debbugging problem, not question for Stack Overflow...

```
var_dump( $Login->checkUserLogin($username,$password) );
```

will return `int(0)` or `bool(false)` or `NULL`